# MustHaveHappened Assert always fails for an async method run on a separate thread (Task.Run)

Tags: c#, multithreading, nunit, fakeiteasy

I have a method:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ILogger _logger;

    public async void TestLogMethod(string msg)
    {
        await Task.Run(async ()=> await _logger.Log(msg));
    }
}
```

And a testcase:

```
[Test]
public async Task TestLogMethod_LogMessage_Test()
{
    var fakeLogger = A.Fake<ILogger>();
    var testClass = new MyClass();
    testClass._logger = fakeLogger;

    testClass.TestLogMethod("Test Message");

    A.CallTo(() => fakeLogger.Log(A<string>._)).MustHaveHappened();
}
```

MustHaveHappened Assert always fails saying

> Assertion failed for the following call:
>      MyClass.TestLogMethod<System.Object>(<Ignored>)
>     Expected to find it at least once but no calls were made to the fake object.

It is clear that _logger.Log() is called, but why is Asserting always failing here ?

Comment: Can you start by explaining why you have an `async void` method which awaits for a new task, which awaits for another task?

Comment: Should also look into [Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

Comment: In my article on [async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), I mention several reasons to avoid `async void` methods; one of them is "Async void methods are difficult to test."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not awaiting the completion of `TestLogMethod`, so you're verifying the expectation before it's happened. The `Task` will be scheduled on the thread pool and the method will then immediately return. This is why you should [avoid async void](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) methods.

Change the method to return a `Task` so you have something to `await`. You can also remove most of the `async` and `await` pairs here as they're redundant:

```
public Task TestLogMethod(string msg)
{
    return Task.Run(() => _logger.Log(msg));
}
```

And then `await` that in your test:

```
await testClass.TestLogMethod("Test Message");
```

And then by the time the verification happens the call to `ILogger.Log` will have happened.